# Iterate and combine iteratively elements in a list

Tags: python, list, combinations

I have a list:

```
li = ['a','b','c','d']
```

I want to iterate and combine iteratively the elements in the list such as the first one is combined to the 2nd one and go on.
The final output I want is:

```
['a'],['a','b'],['a','b','c'],['a','b','c','d']
```

I tried using this way:

```
for i in range(0, len(li),i): 
    output = li[:i+i]
    print(output)
```

But I am getting only this result:

```
[]
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

Any idea where I am wrong and how to do this properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could modify the `start` and `stop` arguments in your use of [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=range#range):

```
li = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
for i in range(1, len(li) + 1):
    output = li[:i]
    print(output)
```

**Output:**

```
['a']
['a', 'b']
['a', 'b', 'c']
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `range` values are incorrect, and `i` is undefined.  This is a much simpler loop:

```
li = ['a','b','c','d']

for i in range(len(li)):
    output = li[:i+1]
    print(i, output)
```

Output:

```
0 ['a']
1 ['a', 'b']
2 ['a', 'b', 'c']
3 ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```